# Logistic regression vs Recommendor system

Tags: logistic, recommender-system

[image]

I am trying to check my understanding with respect to recommendor systems. Here is my reasoning, option (a) is linear regression/neural net set up while option (c) and (d) appears to be standard application of recommendor system.

Regarding option (b), I believe logistic regression would be a better model. However, can we make a claim that in case we have only 1 user then it is "ALWAYS" best to use logistic regression than a recommendor system. If not then please give a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

(a) is  a regression problem, thus methods like linear regression, k nearest neighbors for regression, regression trees, or neural networks (among others) would be suitable. Neither logistic regression nor collaborative filtering is appropriate

(b) Can be solved using logistic regression, by treating the stored characteristics of the websites as the predictors and the outcome (like/dislike) as the outcome. This problem can also be approached by using market basket analysis (aka association rules), if you treat the "like"/"dislike" outcome as one of the features. Since the liking/disliking is collected only on 1 user (i.e. you) rather than a group of users, collaborative filtering does not apply here

(c) this is a situation where collaborative filtering is appropriate as you are trying to recommend a product based on ratings of the user as well as of others' ratings. Assuming that the ratings are non-binary, logistic regression does not apply here

(d) is similar to (c), so you can model the data using collaborative filtering. If the ratings are binary you could also use logistic regression.

Comment: I don't get why option (d) is similar to (b). I am of the opinion that we can use a collaborative filter for this problem since we have multiple users whose preferences (like/dislike) can be treated as ratings 1 or 0.

Comment: Good catch, I meant to say "(d) is similar to (c)" but mistyped. I edited my response and added a clarification. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the response.